# EF Core 5 Upgrade - Query Timeouts

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-2.2

We're belatedly upgrading a successful .net Core 2.1 MVC application to .net Core 5, and everything has gone well, apart from some confusing `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException 'Execution Timeout Expired'` exceptions in a number of queries that used to work perfectly well in EF Core 2.1.

This is an example of one of the queries we're having problems with

```
 var products = await _context.ShopProducts
                    .Include(p => p.Category)
                    .Include(p => p.Brand)
                    .Include(p => p.CreatedBy)
                    .Include(p => p.LastUpdatedBy)
                    .Include(p => p.Variants).ThenInclude(pv => pv.ProductVariantAttributes)
                    .Include(p => p.Variants).ThenInclude(pv => pv.CountryOfOrigin)
                    .Include(p => p.Page)
                    .Include(p => p.CountryOfOrigin)
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                    .Where(p =>
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText)
                            || (
                                    p.Name.Contains(searchText)
                                    || p.Description.Contains(searchText)
                                    || p.Variants.Any(v => v.SKU.Contains(searchText))
                                    || p.Variants.Any(v => v.GTIN.Contains(searchText))
                                    || p.Brand.BrandName.Contains(searchText)
                                    || p.CountryOfOriginCode == searchText
                                    || p.Category.Breadcrumb.Contains(searchText)
                                )
                         )
                    ).ToPagedListAsync(page, pageSize);
```

And the exceptions we're getting.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Span`1 buff, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadChar(Char& value)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadPlpUnicodeCharsChunk(Char[] buff, Int32 offst, Int32 len, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32& charsRead)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadPlpUnicodeChars(Char[]& buff, Int32 offst, Int32 len, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32& totalCharsRead)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlCommandColumnEncryptionSetting columnEncryptionOverride, String columnName, SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnHeader(Int32 i)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method1671(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](Int32 collectionId, QueryContext queryContext, DbDataReader dbDataReader, SingleQueryResultCoordinator resultCoordinator, Func`3 parentIdentifier, Func`3 outerIdentifier, Func`3 selfIdentifier, IReadOnlyList`1 parentIdentifierValueComparers, IReadOnlyList`1 outerIdentifierValueComparers, IReadOnlyList`1 selfIdentifierValueComparers, Func`5 innerShaper, INavigationBase inverseNavigation, Action`2 fixup, Boolean trackingQuery)
   at lambda_method1679(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

This query will work perfectly if the `searchText` parameter is not specfied, so I thought it must be something index / data related, but running the SQL generated for the query, with and without the `searchText` parameter, executes instantaneously when run directly on the database, so it seems to rule out the database as the problem.

Could EF Core 5 be struggling to assemble all the data into object instances? I realise we're returning a large object tree from this query, 152 columns in total, but only 10 rows due to the `pageSize` variable.

As it doesn't time out when no `searchText` is specified, and as EF Core 2.1 was able to put it all together with no problem, that doesn't seem to quite make sense either.

Any suggestions for ways to tune the query, or insights anyone has from their own EF Core 2.1 to 3.1 / 5 upgrades, or anything that leaps out from the exception stack trace would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Apologies for doing my debugging live on SO, but I've found that it's the `p.Description.Contains(searchText)` clause in the query that seems to cause the timeout. If I comment it out, the query runs successfully.

The `Product.Description` data is an HTML string of up to 1028 chars, with an average length of 350 chars, and again, querying this directly in SQL is no problem at all. Could it cause problems for EF in some other way though?

```
[DataType(DataType.Html)]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries-1) to improve performance on queries with lots of Include's.

Comment: Thanks David, this did the trick (event though I'd not had success with applying `.AsSplitQuery()` to other EF 5 queries that timed out). I'm still confused as to why exactly it worked though. As the actual SQL that was being run originally seemed trivial for the db, and ran in a fraction of a second, why would it then cause EF to time out?

Answer (score 2):

The empty search text will work because the composed SQL will ignore any of the other conditions if it is empty. A better way of implementing that would be to keep the condition logic in code rather than the expression:

```
var query = _context.ShopProducts
    .Include(p => p.Category)
    .Include(p => p.Brand)
    .Include(p => p.CreatedBy)
    .Include(p => p.LastUpdatedBy)
    .Include(p => p.Variants)
        .ThenInclude(pv => pv.ProductVariantAttributes)
    .Include(p => p.Variants)
        .ThenInclude(pv => pv.CountryOfOrigin)
    .Include(p => p.Page)
    .Include(p => p.CountryOfOrigin)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Name);

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
    query = query.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchText)
        || p.Description.Contains(searchText)
        || p.Variants.Any(v => v.SKU.Contains(searchText))
        || p.Variants.Any(v => v.GTIN.Contains(searchText))
        || p.Brand.BrandName.Contains(searchText)
        || p.CountryOfOriginCode == searchText
        || p.Category.Breadcrumb.Contains(searchText));

var products = await query.ToPagedListAsync(page, pageSize);
```

Leaving the `if` statement in code ensures these conditions only make it to SQL if they are needed. This is advisable especially where you might have multiple separate search terms and conditionally apply each of them.

The crux of your problem is likely that you are kicking off what will surely be an extremely inefficient query that cannot take advantage of any form of indexing, being a multi `LIKE %{term}%` query. If there is one way to allow users to trigger an effective DDOS against your server, it is this. It will be slow, and users will doubt it started and kick it off repeatedly. (spawning new tabs and such)

In systems there is often a text search capability where there is the possibly of searching across multiple different possible values. You don't do yourself or your users any favours by condensing these down into one uber search. The trouble is that if 95% of the time the search could be directed by the user to the most common type or fields of search it could be considerably faster, but to cater for the 5%, ***all*** searches must be the (s)lowest common denominator.

Some options to consider:

1. Let the user specify what they want to search against. This could be a drop-down multi-select or breadcrumb auto-selecting the most common search target (Name & SKU, etc.)
2. Default to "Begins With" type searching and give the user the option to opt for a slower "Contains" type search.
3. Apply some logic to pre-inspect the search text for what fields it may match. For instance if some of those values are numeric or follow a particular pattern (that a regex could match) then direct the search at those values, or ignore those values if the search text is not appropriate.
4. Always enforce a minimum length check on the search text, or at least whether that search text is applied to certain values.

Changes like this can help keep the 95%+ of the searching as fast and efficient as possible.  I would also consider employing a queuing mechanism for potentially expensive searches where the criteria and pagination data is popped onto a queue with a searchQueueID passed back to the caller which then polls for results using that ID, or can cancel their search. The queue is serviced by a small pool of worker threads that process search requests in sequence and populate a results storage against the searchQueueID and completed status to be picked up by the polling loop. This can help ensure that only so many of these potentially expensive searches are being executed at any given time. (I.e. all kicked off by different users.)

Comment: Thanks for all your thoughts Steve. If EF Core 5 is susceptible to timeouts, for whatever reason, refactoring search UX into searches on specific fields would certainly help it I'm sure. Only applying the `.Where()` clause when actually needed definitely looks clearer in code, and the ideas about pre-inspecting search criteria to then apply them only to relevant fields seems very sensible too.